# Unity - Setting a sprite animation idle to a specific frame and transition smoothly

Tags: unity, animation

I'm new to Unity. I have built an animation with a 2d spritesheet and now I want to transition between idle and walking.

Idle is my frame 1 (or any other frame) and the whole spritesheet animation is running.

When I create the animatorcontroller, I'd set idle as no animation and walking as the animation from the spritesheet, I then assign conditions as paramenter, but when a paramente change, the transition is not smooth, it skips back to the first frame.

How can I make a transition that would, when stopping, continue to animate until the idle frame has been reached, and then stop?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use **Has Exit Time** on the transition and set the **Exit Time** to 1, and the **Transition Duration** to 0.

[image: Transition Settings]

Please leave a comment and add some screenshots of your setup if it doesn't work for you :)